# Android Volly Parsing Error for Nested JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I am trying to post Json data via Android Volly library but getting an error.

Here is my Json body which perfectly working with Postman.

```
{
"fullName": "Mr X",
"fatherName": "Mr Y",
"motherName": "Mrs Z",
"nidNo": "34345",
"surveyDate": "2020-03-25",
"birthCertificateNo": "3435355",
"mobileNumber": "01834261758",
"dateOfBirth": "",
"gender": "Male",
"bloodGroup": "A+",
"numOfDaysSick": "23",
"numOfContInftPerson": "0",
"remarks": "Need Rest",
"physicalSymptoms": ",Runny nose,Sore throat",
"status": "User",
"isForeignVisitor": "false",
"isRead": "false",
"presentAddress": {
    "village": "Sonapur",
    "postOffice": "Noahat",
    "postCode": "1219",
    "upazila": "Sonaimuri",
    "district": "Noakhali",
    "division": "Chittagong"
},
"permanentAddress": {
    "village": "Sonapur",
    "postOffice": "Noahat",
    "postCode": "1234",
    "upazila": "Sonaimuri",
    "district": "Noakhali",
    "division": "Chittagong"
}}
```

But when i try to send it via Android Volly's Post call I am getting the error below :

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Survey of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my Android method to generate this Json body.

Note that : I can successfully generate Json body with this Android method and copy paste(from Logcat) to Postman, it works fine. But Android Volly giving me such error. My url is also ok because I tested it manually.

```
public void SendSurveyDataToServer(){

    customProgressBar.show();
    //--


    //-------------------------------




    JSONObject permanent_address = new JSONObject();
    try {
        permanent_address.put("village", village_pS);
        permanent_address.put("postOffice", post_office_pS);
        permanent_address.put("postCode", post_code_pS);
        permanent_address.put("upazila", upazilla_pS);
        permanent_address.put("district", district_pS);
        permanent_address.put("division", division_pS);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //--


    JSONObject present_address = new JSONObject();
    try {
        present_address.put("village", village_tS);
        present_address.put("postOffice", post_office_tS);
        present_address.put("postCode", post_code_tS);
        present_address.put("upazila", upazilla_tS);
        present_address.put("district", district_tS);
        present_address.put("division", division_tS);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //--

    if(numberofContactedPersonS.equals("Yes")){

        numberofContactedPersonS = "true";
    }else{

        numberofContactedPersonS = "false";
    }

    //--


    //--
    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
    try {
        parameters.put("fullName", fullNameS);
        parameters.put("fatherName", fatherNameS);
        parameters.put("motherName", motherNameS);
        parameters.put("nidNo", nidNoS);
        parameters.put("surveyDate", "2020-03-25");
        parameters.put("birthCertificateNo", birthdayCertificateNoS);
        parameters.put("mobileNumber", mobileNoS);
        parameters.put("dateOfBirth", "");
        parameters.put("gender", gender_selectS);
        parameters.put("bloodGroup", blood_group_selectS);
        parameters.put("numOfDaysSick", sickDaysNoS);
        parameters.put("numOfContInftPerson", "0");
        parameters.put("remarks", remarksS);
        parameters.put("physicalSymptoms", physicalSymptomsS);
        parameters.put("status", statusS);
        parameters.put("isForeignVisitor", numberofContactedPersonS );
        parameters.put("isRead", "false");
        parameters.put("presentAddress", present_address);
        parameters.put("permanentAddress", permanent_address);





    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(classTag,parameters.toString());

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, ApiClass.server_path+ApiClass.saveSurvey, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String respo=response.toString();
                    Log.d(classTag,respo);
                    //iosDialog.cancel();
                    //Parse_signup_data(respo);

                    Log.e(classTag,respo);



                    if(respo.equalsIgnoreCase("Survey Info save Successfully")){


                        Toast.makeText(Survey.this,"Your survey submitted successfully. Thank you!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        //----------------------------------------

                    }else if(respo.equalsIgnoreCase("Survey Info already exits")){


                        Toast.makeText(Survey.this,"Survey info already exist with this NID and Birth Certificate Number!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(Survey.this,"There is an error while submitting your survey, please try again!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Log.e(classTag,"There is an error while submitting your survey, please try again!");

                    }


                    customProgressBar.hide();



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Can't connect with server! Please check your network connection.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    customProgressBar.hide();
                    Log.d(classTag,error.toString());
                }
            });
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    rq.getCache().clear();
    rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);


    //--------------

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for 3 days I found that the problem is **API response**. It was giving me **'Success'** and **'Failed'** in **byte** format but I was always checking the response for **JSONObject** or at least **String**. Postman converted the byte data into string automatically and showed me, for that reason I thought server was giving me the **response** in **string** format.

However, I sent the Json request by Volly's String Request and track the response. Then I found what is messing with me! Our backend developer might be lazy to give a response in String or Json format.

I got the response by converting **byte** to **string** :

```
String string = new String(response.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Here is my modification for this :

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URL = ApiClass.server_path+ApiClass.saveSurvey;
    final String requestBody = parameters.toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            customProgressBar.hide();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            customProgressBar.hide();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

            //customProgressBar.hide();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                String string = new String(response.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Log.e(classTag,string);

               serverMsg = string;
                showServerMsgNow = true;
                Log.e(classTag,"Server msg : "+serverMsg+" server show : "+showServerMsgNow);
               // ShowServerResponse();


            }


            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                // can get more details such as response.headers
            }

            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```